# Compiler skips try bracket?

Tags: java, android

So I have this little App that should only show a JSON-Object(not even parse it) in the Textview "tvJsonItem" after you push the button "btnHit". I have built in multiple Toasts to follow its procedure, but if i push the button, i only get the Toast Test1 from the onPostExecute. It seems like the Programme skips the whole try bracket.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    new JSONTask().execute();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}


public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String result = buffer.toString();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Malformed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You don't have .show() on your Toasts there in catch blocks

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); should be replaced with Log.e(TAG,"message", e);

Comment: Oh well, thats an oversight. i will test it, one second.

Comment: I have added .show() on every Toast, but now i still only get the Toasts "onClick" and "Test1". so no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `toast.show()` in `doInBackground`, because `toast.show()` should call in `Main UI Thread`.

for the test, convert `toast.show()` to `log.d()`...

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the Try bracket is being executed, now i only have to find out why the StringBuffer isnt being written into tvData, but that is a different question.